# sharepoint 2013 custom list item access

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to create a workflow in sharepoint 2013.

I have succeeded in creating the custom list, however now comes my challenge.

I am trying to allow only certain Fields in my custom list available to certain people, the reason for this is because i want different people in my organization to be able to only full out their fields.

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can show items for different people in your organization but for single list fields there is no OUT of the box solution for this you have to write the custom script.